# Recursive find that does not find hidden files or recurse into hidden dirs

Tags: bash, find

I am wanting to search recursively through a directory and find all files that are not hidden files themselves and are not in a hidden dir. I tried using `find . -type f -not -name '.*'` which excludes any base name hidden files, but it still recurses into hidden directories.

```
dir/
   file.py
   .hidden_file
   .hidden_dir/
      file.c
```

I would want the output to be:

```
./dir/file.py
```

however, I get:

```
./dir/file.py
./dir/.hidden_dir/file.c
```

EDIT:
I would like to list only files, i.e., `-type f`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll have to "prune" the directories you don't want to recurse into:

```
find dir -name '.*' -prune -o -print
```

Usually `-prune` is used with `-o` because it returns true, so when combined with short-circuit OR, it has the effect of skipping the `-print` on hidden files / directories, which is exactly what you want.

Comment: Is there anyway to only display the results of type file with this method? I forgot to mention that and adding `-type f` seems to break this.

Comment: Where are you adding `-type f`?  I'd put it between `-o` and `-print`.

Comment: Thanks @jw013 , that was just about the only place I didn't try.

Comment: On more complex expressions you'll need to use parenteses for grouping...